# how to get the user ID without firebase authentication?

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, backend

I'm working on a flutter app that doesn't require an email or password to sign in, it only requires the user to enter his name
my question is, how can I deal with the user data and use his user id without firebase authentication?

is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can save your all users in Cloud Firestore or Firebase Realtime Database

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to identify a user without requiring the to enter credentials, consider using Firebase's [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#anonymous-sign-in). You can then store data in your database associated with that anonymous user's UID.